# ui:repeat h:selectManyCheckbox i can t get values inside a list

Tags: jsf, uirepeat, selectmanycheckbox

I'm working on a JSF 2.2 project , jboss 8.x

I created a dynamic form only with selectManyCheckbox.

I have the following code :

```
<h:form>



                  <table border="5">


 <ui:repeat var="question" value="#{beanQuiz.traninigee.questions}">
      <tr> #{question.question} </tr>

      <tr>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{beanQuiz.questionAnswers[question]}"
                                      converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems  var="response"
                                    value="#{question.responses}"
                                    itemLabel="#{response.reponse}"
                                    itemValue="#{response.responseId}" />
                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>

                </table>
 <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" />
        <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"  styleClass="btn btn-warninig btn-cons m-b-10"/>

        </h:form>
```

selectedArticles is list of entities.

I see on the web the value of a selectManyCheckbox can point to a String[] or List. With this code the selectedArticles don't contains all the checked value, only the latest checked group.

What should i do for getting all the checked values ?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class beanQuiz implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private trainingServiceLocal local;

    private List<Integer> selectedreponses;

    private List<Training> trainings;

    private Training traninigee=new Training();



public String redirectquiz(int idt){

    traninigee=local.findtrainingbyId(idt);



    return "quiz";
}


    public List<Integer> getSelectedreponses() {
        return selectedreponses;
    }

    public void setSelectedreponses(List<Integer> selectedreponses) {
        this.selectedreponses = selectedreponses;
    }

    public int getInc() {
        return inc;
    }

    public void setInc(int inc) {
        this.inc = inc;
    }


    private int inc;

    public Training getTraninigee() {
        return traninigee;
    }

    public void setTraninigee(Training traninigee) {
        this.traninigee = traninigee;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        inc=0;
        trainings = local.findAlltrainings();


        //traninigee=local.findtrainingbyId(1);
        //System.out.println("-----||||||||||||----**---"+traninigee);




    }


//  private static Map<String,Object> color2Value;
//  static{
//      color2Value = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
//      for()
//      color2Value.put("Color2 - Red", "Red"); //label, value
//      
//  }





    public List<Training> getTrainings() {
        return trainings;
    }




    public void setTrainings(List<Training> trainings) {
        this.trainings = trainings;
    }
```

my class diagram  is like that :
i ve got a class of trainings that contrains list of question (onetomany)
my class question contains list of reponses (one to many )
and my class responses is a simple class that contains the response as string 
im using jpa

```
Classe Training 
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="training")
    private List<Question> questions;
}



classe Question 

{

@OneToMany(mappedBy="question",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Respons> responses;

}




classe response {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int responseId;
    private Boolean isValid;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Question

}
```

my list quiz expl .xhtml

```
<ui:repeat var="cat" value="#{beanQuiz.trainings}">




<h:commandButton action="#{beanQuiz.redirectquiz(cat.trainingId)}" value="#{cat.name} " styleClass="btn btn-block btn-success">




</h:commandButton>





<br></br>

</ui:repeat>
```

**and my result page where im going to show the result of checked selectboxes**

```
      <h:form>

           <p>selected responses: </p>

            <br/>

            <p>#{}</p>

 <c:forEach items="#{beanQuiz.questionAnswers.values()}" var="res">


                <p> #{res}</p>
<p>------------</p>
                <br></br>

</c:forEach>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Can you attach some of you backing bean code? At least the relevant parts as it would make it easier to get the picture

Comment: @MaciejKowalski im sorry i ve updated my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is what you have to do:

a) Modify the Backing Bean by removing the List and replacing it with a Map which will pair up questions to the list of answers:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean implements Serializable{


@EJB
private wagentServiceLocal local;

private Training training=new Training();

private Map<Question, List<Integer>> questionAnswers
        = new HashMap<Question, List<Integer>>();

 // When setting up the training to be used in the multiChebox tag
 // set up the map of question to list of chosen responses.
 public String redirectquiz(int idt){

     training=local.findtrainingbyId(idt);

     for(Question question: traninigee.getQuestions()){
           questionAnswers.put(question, new ArrayList<Integer>());            
     }

     return "quiz";
 }

public Map<Question, List<Integer>> getQuestionAnswers() {
    return questionAnswers;
}

public void setQuestionAnswers(Map<Question
              , List<Integer>>     questionAnswers) {
    this.questionAnswers = questionAnswers;
}
```

b) You modify the selectManyCheckBox to use a separate List for each of the Questions:

```
<ui:repeat var="question" value="#{beanQuiz.training.questions}">
      <tr >#{question.question} :
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{beanQuiz.questionAnswers[question]}"
                                      converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems  var="response"
                                    value="#{question.responses}"
                                    itemLabel="#{response.name}"
                                    itemValue="#{response.id}" />
                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
```

Thanks to that, each group of checkboxes will have its own List object and will not be interfered by other groups. 
You just have to change your logic on the way you extract the results for each of the question or use 'questionAnswers.values();', iterate and combine all the responses regardles of the question.

Hope that helps

Comment: Added all the parts now. I have changed a bit the naming to make things more clear for others

Comment: hi maciej i have updated my post with my real case conception i can t apply your solution to my problem can u pls adjust it to my real  case

Comment: Ok i have updated the post and i have come up with a new, better approach which uses Map to pair up the questions to the list of selected answers. Check it out. Again i have refactored the naming a bit.

Comment: that doesn't work i was showing the question with responses but with your solution it doesn t show the question with responses it shows only the question thx for your  help any other suggestion ??

Comment: I have tested this solution and works m8. There is something that you missed. Does your Question class override equals and hash code?

Comment: no i don t im going to update my post with all entites too

Comment: check now pleas

Comment: The bottom line of this topic is that you have to use Map instead of List. Please create a separate topic as i guess you are now facing problem with other part of you logic.

Comment: it works now thank you